# How to keep html selected option from POST data after submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I have an HTML select with default value and I would like to keep Data on this select, if nothing was selected before, I would like to keep the first value like this :

HTML Side :

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control" required>
 <option selected disabled>Gender</option>
 <option value="1">Male</option>
 <option value="2">Female</option>                                                                                                               </select>
```

PHP Side :

```
$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
// I first protected the data with html_entities
$_SESSION['post']['gender']=$this->_dataProtected['gender'];
// I redirect just for test (it works well with other values from input)
header('Location: ?page=children&action=add');
exit();
```

Javascript side :

```
$(window).on('load',function (){
  var idGender = document.getElementById('gender').value = "<?php echo $_POST['gender'] ?? " +          $('#gender').val($('#gender option:first').val()) + " ?>";
});
```

Thank you for your help

The result after submit the form : it fill my select with null value in the case I haven't choose an option and the same when I chose an option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a value passed back from an disabled option. Since the selection is required, instead check if the returned value is NULL, then you know that nothing else was selected.

Example:

```
If (is_null($_SESSION['post']['gender'])) {
    $_SESSION['post']['gender'] = 'Gender';
}
```

With this if/else, you're changing the variable to Gender (The selected disabled option) if the disabled option is "selected".

Comment: Actually, It doesn't change the remains of value after submit if I add an empty string value for my select

Comment: @Bix I changed my response. As said, if the response is NULL, then you know nothing was selected and thereby is "Gender".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you @Stoff,

After adding a `value=""` to option selected, I changed the Javavscript to this :

```
 var idGender = document.getElementById('gender').value = "<?php echo 
  $_SESSION['post']['gender'] ?? '' ?>";
```

And now, its works :D